# Sticky element makes popover content not close

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor, z-index

I am using a MudTable with freeze first 3 columns (with sticky position). The first column has a MudMenu. When I click on the menu, a modal (or popover content) appears with an overlay. The problem is the modal won't disappear when I click on the first three columns (region with sticky position). It makes same modal appears multiple times when I click on other menu.

I tried to change the z-index of all elements but it didn't work.

This seems a common problem with sticky elements and overlay.

[image]

Comment: Modal, that should disappear when you click on the overlay is not disappearing when you click the sticky element? (do I understand it correctly?) 
Isn't this question more related to MudBlazor itself? Are you sure the overlay is above the sticky elements? Can you add an img of modal being opened?

Comment: @Alamakanambra: when I click outside of the table or the fourth column, the modal disappears. The modal is the box with the Edit icon & text. Only the first 3 columns (sticky position) don't make the modal disappear. I think the problem is common in CSS and JS, not just MudBlazor because I saw a similar post without a solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. The question here is "how the modal works"... Can you present a minimal repo with the issue? I can try "things"...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is common with sticky elements and overlays. Have you considered adjusting the z-index of the modal to ensure it's above the sticky elements? Additionally, check for any event listeners or conditions preventing the modal from closing when interacting with the sticky columns.

Comment: As I mentioned in the questions, I already checked the z-index. No particular events or conditions caused this, as I tried to find for many hours. I appreciate your opinion but it is not an answer. Next time, you can leave a comment below the question.